# "Learn a Parametrization of a Manifold" Demo not working

Tags: plotting, neural-networks

I'm trying to go through the Mathmetica online sample here:

[Learn a Parameterization of a Manifold](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/neural-networks/learn-a-parameterization-of-a-manifold.html?product=mathematica)

However, for some reason, when I get to this step

> ```
> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = CoordinateBounds[manifold, .2];
> Show[plot, StreamPlot[ trained[{x, y}] - {x, y}, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}]]
> ```

it doesn't plot the stream lines. I tried on both my local copy of Mathematica as well as the cloud version.

Using `StreamPlot` with any other function *does* work, but doing it with the trained data set just gives an empty/blank image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually it throws a message about non numeric result for given arguments but it is silent now, nevertheless the same fix works:

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := trained[{x, y}] - {x, y};

Show[plot, StreamPlot[f[x, y], {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}]]
```

I'm not entirely sure why and don't have time to investigate but I decided that you will be more interested in answer than explanation.

[image]

Comment: This changed in version 11.0.1.  In 11.0.0, the example works, but I consider that a pure accident.  In 11.0.1, you need the `NumericQ`.  I told support about this mistake in the demo on September 29, and they acknowledged it.  I don't understand why they didn't correct it several months later.